# Is there a 'design pattern' type listing of common algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, self-improvement, resources

Is there a 'design pattern' styled listing of common/popular algorithms anywhere?  Specifically, something that has a similar format along the lines of:

**Algorithm Name:** e.g., Quick Sort, Bubble Sort, etc.
**Problem:** A description of the stereotypical problem the algorithm is supposed to address
**Description:** Description of the solution
**Implementation:** Code examples of the solution
**Big O Rating:** Self-explanatory
**Similar Algorithms:** Algorithms that address the same problem in different ways, or similar problems

I really like the GoF design pattern listing style, and I think it would help me learn various algorithms better/easier if I could find a resource that was similar in terms of organization.

Comment: All you need is this bible - http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844

Comment: While not what you are asking for, the list in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Scheduling is pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/).

<sub>Note SB repository really categorizes problems rather than algorithms.</sub>

For an example of particular algorithm description, take a look at [1.1.1 Dictionaries](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/dictionaries.shtml).

Of the fields you listed, the following are there, some under different names:

- Algorithm Name: name is provided as a section header.
- Problem
- Description: "Excerpt from [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000693)"
- Implementation: "Implementations"
- Similar Algorithms: "Related Problems"

Only *Big O Rating* is not there. For *Dictionaries* section, this makes perfect sense since there is no single rating that would reasonably match different implementations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @gnat While I agree in general, there's not much more to say about it. The OP asked for a *Design Patterns*-like catalog of algorithms, and I pointed to one. I suppose I could have included an image of one of the pages from the site (not so easy from a tablet), and I probably should have explained that the SB repository really categorizes problems rather than algorithms, but there's nothing I can do to convey or summarize the information at the linked site in this case. Feel free to edit if you can improve the answer.

Comment: @gnat. Thank you for your efforts at moderation. Often answers that only contain a link need improvement. But did you read the question this time? How is it possible to answer this question other than by providing a link? Posting the whole algorithm catalogue as an answer? Stonybrook is excellent, +1.

Comment: @MarkJ have you seen changes done to answer in [revision 2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/169884/revisions "look here for details if you're interested")? Side note consider taking a look at MSO posts tagged [link-only-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers)

Comment: @gnat - excellent edit; it really rounded out the answer.

Answer (score 2):

NIST has operated a website called DADS (Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures) at http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/

> This web site is hosted by the [Information Technology Laboratory](http://www.nist.gov/itl/) of the National Institute of Standards and Technology, in collaboration with the [FASTAR group](http://www.fastar.org/).
>
> This is a dictionary of algorithms, algorithmic techniques, data structures, archetypal problems, and related definitions. Algorithms include common functions, such as Ackermann's function. Problems include traveling salesman and Byzantine generals. Some entries have links to implementations and more information. Index pages list entries by area and by type. The two-level index has a total download 1/20 as big as this page...
>
> We do not include algorithms particular to business data processing, communications, operating systems or distributed algorithms, programming languages, AI, graphics, or numerical analysis: it is tough enough covering "general" algorithms and data structures...
>
> *After more than a decade at NIST, this site will move to http://www.fastar.org/dads/ and be hosted by the [FASTAR group](http://www.fastar.org/)*...

Answer (score 1):

This [monstrosity](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-30770-1) might suit your needs if you can [afford](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387307702) it. It includes basically everything you listed except for implementation. It's a proper CS text rather than a programming one per se.